# Is there a image format that starts with 0x4E 0x58 0x50 (ASCII 'NXP')?

Tags: file-format, binary-format

I'm looking at a binary file whose starting bytes are `0x4E 0x58 0x50`. Is this an established magic number for a file format? If so, what format is it? My google-fu has proven too weak to find an answer on the intertubes.

Comment: Where is the file from? What application reads it? What process generated the file? How many samples do you have? If more than 1, are the values of the first 3 bytes consistent across all samples? Is the file corrupted? Is there a header structure with additional fields aside from the first 3 bytes present within the file? How do you know it is an image file? Did you use binwalk to analyze the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a .NPK file. The full signature is `NXPK`.

Use the latest version of quickbms to extract the game.
You can't use offzip because npk files are compressed with lz4.